# Start program on boot C# .Net 5 MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, macos, cross-platform

I'm trying to add a program to launch on boot, and I have been searching far and wide, unable to find a solution for this.

I've come pretty close, I managed to generate a .plist file and added it to ~/Library/LaunchAgents, however I cannot seem to be able to load it. I receive no errors with the code below.

This is the code so far:

```
public static void AddApplicationToStartup()
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + "/Library/LaunchAgents/teststart.plist";
            CreatePlistFile(filePath);

            //string test = $" -c \"osascript -e \' tell application \\\"Terminal\\\" to do script \\\"echo hello\\\" \' \"";
            var arguments = $" -c \"osascript -e \' do shell script \\\"sudo launchctl load -w {filePath}\\\" with administrator privileges\' \"";
            var command = "/bin/bash";

            Console.WriteLine($"Performing: {command} {arguments}");
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = command,
                Arguments = arguments
            };
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // start process
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();


            // read process output
            string cmdError = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine($"cmdError: {cmdError}");
            string cmdOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine($"cmdOutput: {cmdOutput}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

private static void CreatePlistFile(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                PListWriter writer = new PListWriter(filePath, null);
                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
                writer.WriteDocType();
                writer.WriteStartElement("plist");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.0");
                writer.WriteStartElement("dict");
                writer.WriteElementString("key", "Label");
                writer.WriteElementString("string", "com.user.teststart");
                writer.WriteElementString("key", "ProgramArguments");
                writer.WriteStartElement("array");
                writer.WriteElementString("string", "/Applications/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/test_app");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteElementString("key", "RunAtLoad");
                writer.WriteRaw("<true/>");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Plist created");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Plist already exists");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The .plist file works when I run the following through console:

launchctl load -w /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/teststart.plist

But not through the code. I have tried many different changes, such as setting the command and arugments as below.

```
var arguments = $"load -w /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/teststart.plist";
var command = "launchctl";
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or something I can try out?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to add my program to login items for the user by using the following code through Apple Script:

```
var command = "/bin/bash";
var arguments = " -c \"osascript -e ' tell application \\\"System Events\\\" to make login item at end with properties {{path:\\\"/Applications/Shipmondo.app\\\", hidden:false}}'\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you are trying to launch your agent from another program.

When a user logs in, macOS will start a new launchd process for that user. This launchd process will scan the agent directories /System/Library/LaunchAgents, /Library/LaunchAgents and the user's ~/Library/LaunchAgents for property list job files  and will load them depending on the value of the Disabled key (if it exists) and the contents of the override database.

Loading a job definition will not necessarily start the job. When a job is started is determined by the job's property list file. If the RunAtLoad or KeepAlive keys have been specified, then launchd will start the job when as soon as it is loaded.

Apple's documentation on this topic is somewhat outdated to say the least, but for an Overview you can look at the archived https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html, just be aware that some that information is outdated.

Perhaps the best source of information now is the man pages for launchd, launchctl and launchctl.plist.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was most likely misunderstanding how to use mac operations and launchctl specifically. 

I was able to use Login Items to start my program on launch. I have edited the question itself with my solution.

Comment: Mikkel is making an installer i believe (doing this in c# from the app is preferable, sometimes, doing this in nullsoft scripting and all other installer packages can be very time consuming and brittle)- thanks for the code, very useful.